# How to use separate classes (JPA annotations) and JAXB annotations and do the mapping manually

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I'm working with Spring Batch to create a batch application to import data from XML files to MySQL using Hibernate.

This is my current source code: https://github.com/samuelwilsone/filmdata

Currently I'm using JPA and JAXB annotations on same class to mapping data.

I want to use separate classes (JPA annotations) and JAXB annotations and do the mapping manually but I don't know how to begin.

Would you please guide me how to do that? I'm very new with Spring Batch.

Thanks and best regards,

Samuel Wilsone

Comment: What is your goal of separating them out?

Comment: @MichaelMinella: I want to read data from XML by 1 entity and manual mapping to many entities (also do some logic business when map).

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing really requires two classes.  If you're reading XML, then your `ItemReader` would return `MyXmlItem` which is annotated with the JAXB annotations.  From there, you'd have an `ItemProcessor` that transforms `MyXmlItem` into `MyJpaItem` which is annotated with the appropriate JPA annotations (an `ItemProcessor` does not need to return the same item it receives).  This would allow your `ItemWriter` to use the JPA annotations in the persistence of your updates.

Comment: @@MichaelMinella: Thank you so much for your guidance. If can, would you please give me some example how to do as you mention? I'm very newbie in Spring Batch. Sorry for trouble you.